# How to write to HTTP body message parameters AND a zip file?

Tags: java, https

I can not figure out how to correctly post parameters in the request body along side with a zip file.

This is what I have done so far:

```
    HttpsURLConnection connection = openConnection(requestURL);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

    Map<String, String> keyValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    keyValueMap.put("method", "1");
    keyValueMap.put("apiKey", "2");
    keyValueMap.put("merchantUUID", "3");
    keyValueMap.put("batchNotifyURL", "4");
    keyValueMap.put("fileHash", "5");
    keyValueMap.put("urlHash", "6");

    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for(String key : keyValueMap.keySet()) {
            writer.println("--" + boundary);
            writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"");
            writer.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
            writer.println();
            writer.println(keyValueMap.get(key));
        }
        writer.println("--" + boundary);
        writer.println("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"batchFile\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
        writer.println("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");
        writer.println();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileToUpload), "UTF-8"));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                writer.println(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
        writer.println("--" + boundary + "--");
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }
```

The error message that I receive is:
The file submitted is not a valid zip archive.

Is there other way I could do this? Am I missing something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed.
Below is my solution:

```
    OutputStream outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, CHARSET), true);
    try {
        for(String key : keyValueMap.keySet()) {
            writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"").append(CRLF);
            writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + CHARSET).append(CRLF);
            writer.append(CRLF).append(keyValueMap.get(key)).append(CRLF).flush();
        }
        // Send binary file.
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"batchFile\"; filename=\"" + fileToUpload.getName() + "\"").append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Type: " + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileToUpload.getName())).append(CRLF);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(CRLF);
        writer.append(CRLF).flush();
        Files.copy(fileToUpload.toPath(), outputStream);
        outputStream.flush(); // Important before continuing with writer!
        writer.append(CRLF).flush(); // CRLF is important! It indicates end of boundary.
        writer.println("--" + boundary + "--");
    } finally {
        if (writer != null) writer.close();
    }
```